# Mongo-Hadoop sbt package

Tags: macos, mongodb, hadoop, sbt

I am trying to follow the instruction of this page : http://fr.hortonworks.com/blog/pig-as-connector-part-one-pig-mongodb-and-node-js to install Mongo-Hadoop.

I never used [sbt] and have not really understood its way to work even after having look to its official website and wiki page :s

The point is that I understand that [sbt] should create [.jar] files. But it doesn't in my case :(

It should also create a [CORE] and a [PIG] directory, according to [this page](http://chimpler.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/using-hadoop-pig-with-mongodb/). But it doesn't in my case.

Here I make the package :

```
$ sbt package
Unable to find a $JAVA_HOME at "/usr", continuing with system-provided Java...
[info] Set current project to mongo-hadoop (in build file:/Applications/MongoDB/mongo-    hadoop/mongo-hadoop/)
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed 24 oct. 2014 01:09:10
```

And then i look for the JAR :

```
$ find .|grep jar
./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
./target/scala-2.10/mongo-hadoop_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I don't find the expected jar, as the one cited on the documentation :

```
#Expected result not found as of today :
 $ find .|grep jar
 ./core/target/mongo-hadoop-core-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
 ./pig/target/mongo-hadoop-pig-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
 ./target/mongo-hadoop-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Any pointer toward a beginning of solution appreciated :s